# Como fazer um update dinâmico a todas as tabelas do banco de dados para uma coluna específica

Tags: sql-server, servidor, tsql

Pessoal como posso fazer um update dinâmico a todas as tabelas do banco de dados para uma coluna especifica e comum a todas as minhas tabelas?

Eu estou pensando usar a tabela de catálogo para levantar os objectos do banco de dados mas como posso eu construir o update dinâmico para cada tabela que o select me devolve?

Comment: tente explicar com mais detalhes o seu problema. Talvez seja melhor colocar um pedaço de código que já vez para ajudar o entendimento.

Comment: Procure por exemplos de Triggers e Cursores, mas eu não sei se SQL-Server tem isso, a maioria dos banco de dados não usam isso por ser pesado, outra maneira é criar controladores (em código e fora do banco) para realizar todas operações de banco de dados no seu sistema, dai basta atualizar utilizando ele

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução, como refere na pergunta, passa por utilizar o catálogo para obter os nomes das tabelas que pretende actualizar e gerar um conjunto de instruções de update que serão finalmente executadas recorrendo ao procedimento [sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Por exemplo:

```
DECLARE @nomeColuna NVARCHAR(50) = 'aMinhaColuna'    -- nome da coluna que pretende actualizar
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'UPDATE ' + t.name + ' SET ' + @nomeColuna + ' = ''QualquerCoisa'';'
  FROM sys.columns c
 INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
 WHERE c.name = @nomeColuna 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Adicionalmente, recomendo o uso do [QUOTENAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) como medida para mitigar potenciais problemas com colunas que contêm "caracteres especiais".

Fica aqui um pequeno exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6713a/7).

Nota: Esta solução pressupõe que o banco de dados não possui um número muito elevado de tabelas. Nesse caso pode alterar a solução para usar um laço/ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Avalie o uso do procedimento sp_MSforeachtable.

```
-- código #1
USE nome_banco;

EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE ? set coluna= valor;'
```

No código acima substitua `coluna` pelo nome da coluna e `valor` pela expressão cujo resultado será armazenado na coluna. Por exemplo, se o nome da coluna é `Ativo` e é para zerar o conteúdo dela, temos

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE ? set Ativo= 0;'
```

O procedimento `sp_MSforeachtable` possui alguns parâmetros de utilização opcional, que são úteis em casos mais complexos.