# Comando para atualizar várias tabelas no banco de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

É possível fazer uma atualização no meu banco de dados da seguinte maneira :
Minhas tabelas no banco de dados possuem um campo `emp_codigo` ? eu gostaria de atualizar o valor de todos que tem no banco de dados para `1`

Não sei se entenderam, mas exemplo:

Tenho `x` tabelas com o mesmo campo `emp_codigo` e cada tabela tem um número `x` de tuplas e quero atualizar todas as tuplas de todas as tabelas no campo `emp_codigo` para receber valor `1`, é possível?

Comment: Acredito que esta pergunta já foi respondida neste link: [Como fazer um update dinâmico a todas as tabelas do banco de dados para uma coluna específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275841/como-fazer-um-update-din%C3%A2mico-a-todas-as-tabelas-do-banco-de-dados-para-uma-colu)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um update dinâmico a todas as tabelas do banco de dados para uma coluna específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275841/como-fazer-um-update-din%c3%a2mico-a-todas-as-tabelas-do-banco-de-dados-para-uma-colu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jeff Henrique, boa tarde

Não existe uma maneira de você fazer isso com um único comando.
Terá que montar todos os UPDATEs mesmo, um por tabela, atualizando o valor da sua coluna emp_codigo.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente não existe uma forma de fazer tudo em um único update.
Dependendo da frequência em que você precisa fazer isso, uma saída seria criar uma procedure que receba o parâmetro a ser persistido, e todos os comandos updates ficariam dentro desta procedure.

Dessa forma:

```
EXEC atualiza_dados meu_param
```

Ai dentro da tua procedure, ficaria o código com os updates.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE...
declare @meu_param
...

UPDATE table1 set emp_codigo = @meu_param where ...
UPDATE table2 set emp_codigo = @meu_param where ...
UPDATE table3 set emp_codigo = @meu_param where ...
```

Dessa forma, se você precisar novamente ficar aplicando updates constantes nas mesmas tabelas, basta executar a procedure, já que a sua ideia é que todos os campos recebam o mesmo valor.